# xpages link in new tab ignoring validations

Tags: xpages

I have the following link on my footer layout:

```
<xp:link escape="true" id="link1" text="Click me" target="_blank">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete">
                        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("http://www.example.com")}]]></xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

The main layout contains some required fields. If I click the link I will get the message: "That field is required!" and so on. But, if I click the link in my main page ( which is something like a home page ) , the URL redirects me to the respective site, but on the same tab. Is `target="_blank"` ignored?

How can I achieve this considering I want when clicking on link the validations to be ignored and the url to be opened on new tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using server-side logic to determine the target/URL to load. Your client-side properties are therefore ignored.

Do this instead:

```
<xp:link escape="true" id="link1" text="Click me" target="_blank" value="http://www.example.com">
</xp:link>
```

You also calculate the URL in advance:

```
<xp:link escape="true" id="link1" text="Click me" target="_blank" value="http://www.example.com">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        if (something) {
            return "http://example.org";
        } else {
            return "http://example.com";
        }
    }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:link>
```